# Why does printf create windows line endings?

Tags: c, printf, mingw

So I'm trying to copy (and later modify) a .ppm file. I'm on Windows 10 using mingw g++.
The original file is LF only but the one created with my program has CRLF which breaks the .ppm file. I'm not doing \r\n anywhere but it still gets outputted.

```
FILE *fp;
FILE *dest;

char magicNumber[3];
int width, height, depth;
unsigned char red, green, blue;
unsigned char* buff;

printf("Hello, World!\n");


fp = fopen("lenna.ppm", "r+");

fscanf(fp, "%s", magicNumber);
fscanf(fp, "%d %d %d", &width, &height, &depth);
printf("%s %d %d %d nums\n", magicNumber, width, height, depth);


dest = fopen("lena2.ppm", "w+");
fprintf(dest, "%s\n%d %d\n%d", magicNumber, width, height, depth);
```

Results in

[image]

WHY?

I want to only have LF. How do I do that?

Comment: You're getting Windows line endings because you're on Windows, with a non-binary-mode file, and the stdio functions thus translate a newline into a carriage return and newline (And vis versa on reading files).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Open your file in binary mode:

```
fopen("lena2.ppm", "wb+");
```

From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/fopen-wfopen?view=vs-2019):

> In text mode, carriage return-line feed combinations are translated
>   into single line feeds on input, and line feed characters are
>   translated to carriage return-line feed combinations on output.

Comment: @ditoslav: For completeness, just make sure you `fclose()` the file.